# Issues with implementing TensorFlow's MNIST example without feed_dict using a queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, mnist, tensorflow

I came across TensorFlow's [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) and wanted to adapt it for more efficient use on GPUs. Since feed_dict seems to be incredibly slow, I implemented an input pipeline using `tf.train.shuffle_batch` and a `FIFOQueue` to feed data into the model.

[Here's a Gist with the stock implementation of the TensorFlow guide](https://gist.github.com/noahfl/65b8c0e56b39e58affc5f63b4915dfd3) and [here's a Gist with my attempt at an optimized implementation.](https://gist.github.com/noahfl/0b244346d4ad2501718bbb226be16b1e)

Now in the example on the TensorFlow page, the accuracy pretty quickly approaches 1 after a few thousand iterations. However in my code, which aside from the queue implementation is the same model, the accuracy seems to oscillate between ~0.05 and ~0.15. Further, the loss reaches about 2.3 after a couple hundred iterations and doesn't decrease much farther than that.

Another noteworthy point: when I make a comparison to the original batch created and the batch used in subsequent iterations, they appear to be equivalent. Perhaps the issue lies in my queuing/dequeuing but I'm not really sure how to fix it. If anyone sees any issues with my implementation some pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Turns out `tf.train.shuffle_batch` implicitly implements a `RandomShuffleQueue`. Loading the results of `tf.train.shuffle_batch` into a `FIFOQueue` presumably caused the `FIFOQueue` to not update the input batch, while the labels were being updated because they weren't being passed into the `FIFOQueue`. Removing the `FIFOQueue` entirely solved my issue.